# asking for microphone permissions for android

Tags: flutter, permissions, text-to-speech, microphone

I added a text-to-speech searcher for my app, so I can filter a list with speech, It works all fine the only thing is I have to accept the permissions manually from the permissions options tab of the app.

I'm using the [speech_recognition](https://pub.dev/packages/speech_recognition) package for it.

also in the `android.Manifest.xml` file at app>src>main I've added this

`<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" />`

In the console I get this error if I do not accept the permissions manually

> I/flutter (12585): _platformCallHandler call
>   speech.onSpeechAvailability false
>
> I/flutter (12585): _platformCallHandler call speech.onError 9
>
> I/flutter (12585): Unknowm method speech.onError

is there any other way so the system asks me to accept it when I for example click the speech icon?

Comment: You might want to check https://pub.dev/packages/permission_handler

Comment: I was hoping to do it without a package

Comment: You could do that without a package but you'll have to write android native code for that. Packages were made to simplify and shorten code so it is recommended that you use them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So I used [permission_handler](https://pub.dev/packages/permission_handler)

I just create a `Future` like this:

```
  Future askForPermissions() async {
        Map<PermissionGroup, PermissionStatus> permissions = await PermissionHandler().requestPermissions([PermissionGroup.microphone]);
}
```

and then on click of a `IconButton` called that
it's working fine,